# SQL Server - Query With Multiple Date Ranges in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range

I have used conditional aggregation in another query where I needed to use multiple date ranges. In this case the date ranges are needed in a sub-query.

I would like to know if can I get desired results in one single query (without using UNION).

I need to check if a given record EXISTS in the subquery with date-range. Since I need to use EXISTS rather than a join - I am running into this issue.

Here is a sample script/data. The expected results table is for demonstration.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Entity') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Entity
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EntityDate') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #EntityDate
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExpectedOutput') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ExpectedOutput

> `DECLARE @FortnightStart DATETIME = '2020/08/01', @FortnightEnd DATETIME = '2020/08/14 23:59:59'
DECLARE @QuarterStart DATE = '2020/04/01', @QuarterEnd DATE = '2020/06/30 23:59:59'


> `SELECT 'Fortnight' DateRange, @FortnightStart 'Start', @FortnightEnd 'End'
UNION
SELECT 'Quarter', @QuarterStart, @QuarterEnd 

CREATE TABLE #Entity (
    EntityId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    EntityName VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #EntityDate (
    EntityDateId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    EntityId INT,
    SubmittedDate DATETIME
)

ALTER TABLE #EntityDate ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EntityDate_Entity FOREIGN KEY (EntityId) REFERENCES Entity(EntityId)


INSERT INTO #Entity (EntityName) 
SELECT 'Alice'
UNION
SELECT 'Bob'
UNION
SELECT 'Cameron'
UNION
SELECT 'Diego'
UNION
SELECT 'Elliot'



SELECT * FROM #Entity


INSERT INTO #EntityDate(EntityId, SubmittedDate)
SELECT 1, '08/01/2020 11:00:00' -- only 1 record is expected in the output for this Entity
UNION
SELECT 1, '08/10/2020 10:00:00' 
UNION
SELECT 1, '04/10/2020 10:00:00'  -- this record should show up for the quarter date range
UNION
SELECT 2, '06/01/2020 11:00:00'  -- 
UNION
SELECT 3, '05/01/2020'  -- only 1 record is expected in the output for this Entity
UNION
SELECT 3, '06/01/2020' 
UNION
SELECT 4, '10/01/2021' -- does not fit in any date range
UNION
SELECT 5, '08/02/2020' 


SELECT *
FROM #EntityDate d
    INNER JOIN #Entity e ON d.EntityId = e.EntityId


SELECT * 
FROM #Entity E
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                FROM #EntityDate d
                WHERE SubmittedDate BETWEEN @FortnightStart AND @FortnightEnd AND e.EntityId = D.EntityId
                )

SELECT * 
FROM #Entity E
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1 
                FROM #EntityDate d
                WHERE SubmittedDate BETWEEN @QuarterStart AND @QuarterEnd AND e.EntityId = D.EntityId
                )

CREATE TABLE #ExpectedOutput
(       
    EntityId INT,   
    DateRange VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #ExpectedOutput (EntityId, DateRange)
SELECT 1, 'Fortnight'
UNION 
SELECT 5, 'Fortnight'
UNION 
SELECT 1, 'Quarter'
UNION 
SELECT 2, 'Quarter'
UNION 
SELECT 3, 'Quarter'


SELECT o.*, e.EntityName
FROM #ExpectedOutput o
    INNER JOIN #Entity e ON o.EntityId = e.EntityId
ORDER BY O.DateRange, o.EntityId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the virtual Dates table you created at the top of your script, you need to join that to `Entity`, using the `EXISTS` as the `ON` condition

```sql
DECLARE @FortnightStart DATETIME = '2020/08/01', @FortnightEnd DATETIME = '2020/08/14 23:59:59';
DECLARE @QuarterStart DATE = '2020/04/01', @QuarterEnd DATE = '2020/06/30 23:59:59';

WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT 'Fortnight' DateRange, @FortnightStart Start, @FortnightEnd [End]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Quarter', @QuarterStart, @QuarterEnd
)
SELECT
  e.EntityId,
  d.DateRange
FROM Dates d
JOIN #Entity E ON EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM #EntityDate ed
    WHERE ed.SubmittedDate BETWEEN d.Start AND d.[End]
      AND ed.EntityId = e.EntityId
    );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b18625715afafd2088d31bfd00e11a29)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1, '08/01/2020 11:00:00'),
(1, '08/10/2020 10:00:00'),
(1, '04/10/2020 10:00:00'),
(2, '06/01/2020 11:00:00'),  -- 
(3, '05/01/2020'),
(3, '06/01/2020'), 
(4, '10/01/2021'),
(5, '08/02/2020') 
) EntityIDate(EntityId,SubmittedDate)
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/select-selecting-from-the-values-table-value-constructor

Comment: Each entity should appear appear only once in the date range (e.g. Fortnight or Quarter) if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have such requirement ? What is harm in using multiple `UNION ALL` ? Performance wise there is no harm.

I hope I understood your requirement correctly.

```
DECLARE @FortnightStart DATETIME = '2020/08/01', @FortnightEnd DATETIME = '2020/08/14 23:59:59'
DECLARE @QuarterStart DATE = '2020/04/01', @QuarterEnd DATE = '2020/06/30 23:59:59'

;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT 1 AS Orderflg, 
                'Fortnight' DateRange, 
                @FortnightStart 'StartDate', 
                @FortnightEnd 'EndDate'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 
                'Quarter', 
                @QuarterStart, 
                @QuarterEnd),
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityId, 
                                               Orderflg
                ORDER BY SubmittedDate) rn
         FROM #EntityDate d
              CROSS APPLY
         (
             SELECT TOP 1 DateRange, 
                          Orderflg
             FROM CTE C
             WHERE SubmittedDate >= StartDate
                   AND SubmittedDate < EndDate
         ) ca -- e.EntityId = D.EntityId
         )
     SELECT e.EntityId, 
            DateRange, 
            EntityName
     FROM CTE1 C1
          INNER JOIN #Entity E ON c1.EntityId = e.EntityId
     WHERE rn = 1
     ORDER BY Orderflg;
```

Comment: I think union all will not be efficient - also just trying to check if this is doable - I was not sure it was when I posted the question.

Comment: Certainly UNION was silly mistake i didn't notice.